# How do I hide arrays php with an empty value of 0?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have to hide all empty arrays from the result or with value = 0. How can I do?

```
$return_arr = array();
$fetch = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT...");
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
   $row_array['id'] = $row['ordr'];
        $row_array['name'] = $row['name'];
        $row_array['icon'] = $row['icon'];
        $row_array['file_a'] = $row['file_a'];
        $row_array['file_b'] = $row['file_b'];
        $row_array['file_c'] = $row['file_c'];
        $row_array['file_r'] = $row['file_r'];

        array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
    }
    $response_arr = json_encode($return_arr);
    return $response_arr;
    }
```

Comment: as its from a db query, why not exclude those rows in the query `SELECT ... where value !=0`

Comment: You could also research `count()` to count elements in array

Answer (score 0):

There is missing code from your function so I have worked with what is available.

Try selecting only the cols you want data from and then check if col is empty per row. If there is a column that has data then the whole row is returned.

```
    $return_arr = array();
    $fetch = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT name,icon,file_a,file_b,file_c,file_r FROM...");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $tmp = 0;
        foreach( $row as $key => $val ){
            if( !empty($row[$key]) ) $tmp++;
        }
        if( $tmp > 0 ) array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
    }
    $response_arr = json_encode($return_arr);
    return $response_arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also `array_filter` might be helpful as it can exclude all false values on the results set (used without callback).

[More info on array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)